# Running a loop on the complete variable after iterating on all the categories of that field

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I am working in R and I have a dataframe which consists of columns with categorical data. On each of these combinations of categories, I have to aggregate a metric.
Input table:

```
ID  Region  Access  Touchpoints
A   Central High    8
B   Central Low     7
C   West    High    7
D   West    Low     3
E   Central High    2
F   Central Low     5
G   West    High    9
H   West    Low     8
```

Output which I want:

```
Region  Access  Touchpoints
All     All     49
All     High    26
All     Low     23
Central High    10
West    High    16
Central Low     12
West    Low     11
Central All     22
West    All     27
```

Problem is I have to create an *All* category when iterating these variables in nested loops. Is there any other way?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, could you provide a minimal reproducible example? I mean, a sample dataset and what have you done so far?. Dataset could be in the form `dataset <- data.frame(cola = c(...), colb = c(...), )` We are glad to help if you give us the tools.

Comment: @Manu Could you pl tell me how to insert a table here?

Comment: Of course!, when writing use 3 backticks to start this sample code: `dataset <- data.frame(Access = c("All","All","All","High"), Region = c("All","Central","West","All"), Touchpoints = c(45, 34, 11, 23), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. If you have the data in a data frame you could use `dput(yourdata)`in R and copy the data it gives in SO.

Comment: @Manu Thank you. Hope the question is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New answer

The question is somewhat hard to make out. But what the questioner is looking for is **aggregates and totals** in several groupings variables. The `cube` function from `data.table` is specifically designed for this scenario.

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread('ID  Region  Access  Touchpoints
A   Central High    8
B   Central Low     7
C   West    High    7
D   West    Low     3
E   Central High    2
F   Central Low     5
G   West    High    9
H   West    Low     8')
result <- cube(df, j = sum(Touchpoints), by = c('Region', 'Access'))
```

Note that `cube` only accepts a `data.table` and returns one as well. For more information on the `data.table` package I refer to their excellent cheat-sheet like wiki [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki). In the result `NA` mark totals in groups and subgroups. We can get change this and get back to a data.frame by running

```
df[is.na(Region), Region = 'All'][is.na(Access), Access := 'All']
setDF(df) #Change back to DF (if wanted)
```

## Old answer

This will be a somewhat limited answer due to the lack of a reproducible example.

Depending on the size of your data and your available memory, the simplest method for these situations is to simple create a grid of all combinations to iterate over. Multiple methods exist. In base R

```
combinations <- expand.grid(var1, var2, var3, ...) 
for(i in seq(nrow(combination))){
   current_comb <- combinations[i, ] 
   #Do stuff
   #...
}
#Alternative
#apply(combinations, 1, FUN)
```

With `data.table` we could similarly use `CJ(var1, var2, ...)` and with `tidyverse` we'd use `expand_grid`.

This is often much faster, but as the number of categories grow this is going to become less and less feasible. In your situation it should do fine however.

Comment: thank you. I have added a reproducible example now as requested.

Comment: Hi @SrikanthGuhan. My answer has been updated to accomodate your changes.